# How to create conditional build in Xcode Project? Either using Macro or setting global bool variable

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Xcode Project: How to create conditional build via Xcode Project

I had tried to define preprocessed macro such as LIGHTER_VERSION_APP at target or project level setting. Now I'm trying to use this macro in the other dependent project of my main project. I'm not able to use this LIGHTER_VERSION_APP macro in other dependent project.

Can anybody tell me how I can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Xcode project or target settings, under the compiler settings, you can add any flags you like to "Other C Flags" and "Other C++ Flags". You can simply add "-D LIGHTER_VERSION_APP" and it should now be defined when compiling your project. Once that's done, you can use `#if defined LIGHTER_VERSION_APP` in your code to turn stuff on or off.

Comment: I tried C++ Flags and also Preprocess Macro however I was facing issue while using the macro in other dependency of my main project. My main project has some other project dependency (dylibs and some as a framework).

Comment: What issues are you seeing? Is there any error message output?